# Using Simple Search to look in an entry's selected categories?

Tags: categories, simple-search

I have a simple search form set to look in entries. When I search for the category name that I have selected in some entries, the entry does not show in the results. Should I be able to use Simple Search to look in an entries selected categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eeDelve,

The EE search module searches the content of entries - it will not look for names of categories.  You may need to look at some of the third-party options for that.

Here's a quick list of add-ons that that may help out.  Look to Low Search and Solspace Super Search first, would be my suggestions.  See this [search for 'search' on Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=search&addon_version_support=ee2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an add-on called Categories to Text which will save all an entry's categories into a channel field automatically.

- github: http://github.com/shoeshine/categories-to-text
- devot-ee: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/categories-to-text